# Is it possible load all properties files contained in a package dynamically? i.e. MyClass.class.getResource('*.properties');

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, properties, classpath, classloader

I am familiar with obtaining the contents of a properties file given the name of the file, and obviously MyClass.class.getResource('*.properties') will not work, but how can I obtain a list of ALL the properties files located in the same package as my class?

Comment: This is easy with Spring, so on the off-chance you're using it, I can give you a Spring-based answer.

Comment: Ok... so I am starting to think this isn't possible.  From my understanding Java uses lazy classloading and therefore the classloader doesn't know what is in a package until it is asked to retrieve a class.  The closest thing I can come up with is to *attempt* to resolve a package name to directory, get a list of prop. files in the dir, and attempt to load them via the class.getResource().  I know that's a hack; is there a better way?

Comment: Aha! That sounds like it would work, any answering utilizing Spring is quite acceptable and would be much appreciated

Comment: please post targeted comments with `@nickname`, such as @skaffman so that he get notified about it :) And yes, it's nasty to do so with `java.io.File` and consorts. And yes, a Spring solution would be nicer.

Comment: @skaffman Any Spring solution you can provide would be extremely helpful.  Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do these sort of things with **Spring**. See [4. Resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html), particurlarely (or notabily ? ) (or principalementely ? ) (or mainly ? ) at [4.7.2 Wildcards in application context constructor resource paths](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx-wildcards-in-resource-paths).

Comment: Curses, someone stole my thunder :) Have a cookie. +1

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that it's not JAR-packaged, you can use [`File#listFiles()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) for this. Here's a kickoff example:

```
String path = MyClass.class.getResource("").getPath();
File[] propertiesFiles = new File(path).listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".properties");
    }
});
```

If it's JAR-packaged, then you need a bit more code, to start with [`JarFile` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html). You can find another example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839671/finding-installed-jdbc-drivers/1840104#1840104).

Comment: Sorry, no File allowed.  Class is currently not in a jar... but I do not know what the future holds for my class and I have no control over the enviroment this will be run in, so it needs to be as decoupled as possible

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it,

```
Class<? extends Object> clazz = AnyKnownClassInTheJar.class;
String classFileName = clazz.getSimpleName() + ".class";
URL classResource = clazz.getResource(classFileName);
if (!"jar".equals(classResource.getProtocol())) {
    // Class not from JAR
    return;
}
JarURLConnection classConnection = (JarURLConnection)classResource.openConnection();
JarFile jar = classConnection.getJarFile();
for (Enumeration<JarEntry> i = jar.entries(); i.hasMoreElements();) {
    JarEntry entry = i.nextElement();
    if (entry.getName().endsWith(".properties")) {
        // Load the property file
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This even works on Android. The trick there is to start with `classResource = AnyClassInTheApp.class.getResource("/AndroidManifest.xml")`. The entries listed in the jar will be the APK contents.