# Loading All Properties Resource Bundle From Application

Tags: java, spring, properties, resourcebundle

> Is there any possibility or any program available to read all the .properties file available in application using `Resource Bundle API`.?
>   I want to search the whole application and load all the properties once.

Something Like Below Code.

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test.bundletest.mybundle");
    Enumeration <String> keys = rb.getKeys();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = keys.nextElement();
        String value = rb.getString(key);
        System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
```

and This Statement returns only one bundle

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test.bundletest.mybundle");
```

But what if I want to do like load all **("*.properties")** Like this .. Then is it possible?

Comment: This topic has answers to your question :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960355/is-it-possible-load-all-properties-files-contained-in-a-package-dynamically-i-e

Comment: @Berger : Thanks for your info but I want to load only all *.properties file within an application.